# Show part of a very large image to user without downloading the whole image file - php

Tags: php, google-maps, image-processing

I have very large images of plants (about 40MB) and want to show these to users. 
But here is the question: If the user wants to see only part of an image (e.g. only the root of a plant) how to tell browser to download only that part not the full size image.
I think about something like Google maps that shows a very large image of the world without the details, but when you are zooming on a part of the map you only download that part.

Comment: Try Googling `DeepZoom` and `DZSAVE` and looking at http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the google maps approach by creating a grid from the image.
With imagemagick you could split the image in a grid of multiple images. From each image you create a thumbnail so you can combine it to a small image.

When the user clicks on one of these thumbnails in your composed small picture, you link them to the corresponding big image part.